# Creating link opacity boxes in css hompeage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having difficulty making my opacity boxes for a webpage. I can make the boxes and the words to go in them separately but then the words do not seem to change font or color which i need them too. Can anyboy help. Here is my code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: bold;
  src: url(Font-Bold.otf);
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'bold';
}
div.current {
  position: absolute;
  top: 248px;
  left: 370px;
}
div.others {
  position: absolute;
  top: 248px;
  left: 530px;
  color: black;
}
div.transbox1 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 200px 350px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
div.transbox2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -232px 510px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
 <h1>otago university hockey club</h1>
<div class="transbox1"></div>
<div class="transbox2"></div>
<div class="current">
  <p><a href="#">Current Players</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="others">
  <p><a href="#">All The Others</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are juist wanting the background colour opaque you can use rgba colours: `background-colour:rgba(0,0,0,0.6)` - [More info](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: I am just wanting two boxes opaque with words in them. These serve as my hompage menu items

Comment: Well then you couldn't you just put the links in the box and give them an opaque background or do you want the words to be opaque as well?

Comment: Ah yea not the word opaque but currently when i try change the color of the words it won't let me. They just stay their default underlined purple

Comment: you need to style the link - so `.current a { color:red; }` or `.others a {}`

Comment: Thank you Pete. Sorry for the basic question. Still new to this

Comment: @Seb hey man, check this [LINK](http://hastebin.com/ucofezagot.coffee) out, about your other question